# Mapping API with Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use data returned via their API from weather site in an Android app:  https://openweathermap.org/current

I am using the GET approach using a zip code, and the response is shown as an example on the above page.

Here it is:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-122.09,"lat":37.39},
"sys":{"type":3,"id":168940,"message":0.0297,"country":"US","sunrise":1427723751,"sunset":1427768967},
"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01n"}],
"base":"stations",
"main":{"temp":285.68,"humidity":74,"pressure":1016.8,"temp_min":284.82,"temp_max":286.48},
"wind":{"speed":0.96,"deg":285.001},
"clouds":{"all":0},
"dt":1427700245,
"id":0,
"name":"Mountain View",
"cod":200}
```

Here is my "results" class:

```
public class WeatherResults {

        private Integer temp;

        public Integer getTemperature() {
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

Here is the interface I wrote for sending the request to OpenWeather:

```
public interface WeatherClient {

    @GET("/data/2.5/weather?zip={zipcode}&APPID=xxx")
    Call<WeatherResults> weatherReturned(@Query("zipcode") String zipcode);
    //@Path("zip")
}
```

Here is where I interact with Retrofit 2:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        WeatherClient client = retrofit.create(WeatherClient.class);
        Call<WeatherResults> call = client.weatherReturned("08003)");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResults>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse
            (Call < WeatherResults > call, Response < WeatherResults > response){
                WeatherResults weatherReturned = response.body();
                Log.e("Weather", Integer.toString(weatherReturned.getTemperature()));
         //       Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(weatherReturned.getTemperature()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure (Call < WeatherResults > call, Throwable t){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I am getting a compile error in Android Studio 3:  URL query string "zip={zipcode}&APPID=xxx" must not have replaced the block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.  I don't see how to fix this.
2. I am pretty sure that I don't have the code right in my results class, but I can't figure out what it should look like.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: why are you using Integer and not Double ?

Comment: I've added an answer on your question number 1. I can't understand your question number 2, what do you want to catch from the response of the API?

Answer (score 0):

Your `retrofit` parsing for `query parameter` is wrong, you're using the `url parameter`. This is how you're going to format a `query parameter`:

```
public interface WeatherClient {

   @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
   Call<WeatherResults> weatherReturned(
      @Query("zip") String zipcode,
      @Query("APPID") String appId
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting a compile error in Android Studio 3: URL query string "zip={zipcode}&APPID=xxx" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query. I don't see how to fix this.

The "replace block" the error code mentions is the part of your path surrounded with curly braces. In your case, this is `{zipcode}`. This "replacement" technique is used when you need a dynamic *path* (like `group/{id}/users`), but you only need a dynamic *query string*. For this, you can simply use the `@Query` annotation and Retrofit will automatically build the query string for you.

Your original `@GET` uses this: `/data/2.5/weather?zip={zipcode}&APPID=xxx`. Only the `/data/2.5/weather` part is the *path*, so that's all that should be in the `@GET` annotation. The rest is the query string. The string you use in the `@Query` annotation will be used as the key, and the value you pass will be used as the value.

All together, you can get what you're looking for with this:

```
@GET("/data/2.5/weather")
Call<WeatherResults> weatherReturned(@Query("zip") String zipCode,
                                     @Query("APPID") String appId);
```

> I am pretty sure that I don't have the code right in my results class, but I can't figure out what is should look like.

Here's a formatted and trimmed-down version of the api response:

```
{
  "coord": {...},
  "sys": {...},
  "weather": [...],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 285.68,
    "humidity": 74,
    "pressure": 1016.8,
    "temp_min": 284.82,
    "temp_max": 286.48
  },
  "wind": {...},
  "clouds": {...},
  "dt": 1427700245,
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Mountain View",
  "cod": 200
}
```

I assume the `temp` field you're looking for is the subfield of the `main` object. Your response class needs to represent this top-level object, so you'll need to create (at least) two classes: one to represent the `main` object and one to represent the top-level response.

```
public class MainObject {
    private double temp;
    private int humidity;
    ...
}

public class WeatherResults {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private MainObject main;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Tenten's answer is right for number one. 
   you dont need to write query parameter on url, hence only need this url "/data/2.5/weather".
2. Your result class should have the same structure as your json, and  minimally should contain the most outter json object.
   You can use tools like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create the pojo automatically, just make sure to select the source type to Json.